# Can I pass the values of a matrix to another matrix by simultaneously indexing both matrices in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am writing a piece of code that uses a struct and 5 predefined functions, I am having problems passing the values of the input 2d array at a chosen index to a new 2d array.

I have included my functions and the code for function I am having difficulties with.

```
struct matrix
{
char name;
int mValues[10][10];
int ncols;
int nrows;
};

void matrixInput(struct matrix *matA);
void matrixDisplay(struct matrix matA);
void matrixTrace(struct matrix matA, int *trace);
void matrixDeterminant(struct matrix m1, struct matrix *m2, int * determinant);


///function body 
void matrixDeterminant(struct matrix m1, struct matrix *m2, int * determinant)
{
int i, j, k, l;
FILE* fin;
fin = fopen("marks.txt", "r");
if(((m1.nrows)>2))
{
    printf("\n\nFinding the deterinamt now.\n");
    if(fin!=NULL)
    {
        do
        {
             printf("Please assign a letter to name your matrix A - Z : ");
             scanf(" %c", &((*m2).name));
        }
             while((((*m2).name)<'A') || ((*m2).name)>'Z');
        do
        {
             printf("\n\nEnter the row where you want to start the 2x2 matrix.\nNumber needs to be between 1 and %d : ", ((m1).nrows-1));
             scanf("%d", &k);
        }
             while((k) >= ((m1).nrows));
        do 
        {
             printf("\n\nEnter the column where you want to start you 2x2 mtrix.\nNumber needs to be between 1 and %d : ", ((m1).ncols-1));
             scanf("%d", &l);
        }
             while((l) >= ((m1).ncols));
    }

    for(i=0; i<2; i++,k++)
        {
             printf("Row %d:\t", i+1);

             for(j=0; j<2; j++,l++)
                 {
                    ((*m2).mValues[i][j]) = ((m1).mValues[k-1][l-1]);
                    printf("%d\t",((*m2).mValues[i][j])); 
                 }
                 printf("\n");
        }

}

/// Input/Output
Please assign a letter to name your matrix A - Z : H

Please enter the number of rows in matrix H > 1 < 10 :8

Please enter the number of cols in matrix H > 1 < 10 :8

Matrix H has 8 rows and 8 columns and contains:

Row 1:  55  7   40  30  32  45  43  77
Row 2:  72  1   20  65  85  40  46  22  
Row 3:  45  77  88  32  30  55  59  99  
Row 4:  72  37  33  18  44  73  44  12  
Row 5:  88  2   11  55  7   40  30  32  
Row 6:  24  73  13  99  99  22  45  77  
Row 7:  88  32  22  11  98  34  38  37  
Row 8:  33  18  44  73  22  45  77  88 

Trace of matrix H = 317 

Finding the deterinamt now.
Please assign a letter to name your matrix A - Z : F

Enter the row where you want to start the 2x2 matrix.
Number needs to be between 1 and 7 : 3

Enter the column where you want to start you 2x2 mtrix.
Number needs to be between 1 and 7 : 3
Row 1:  88  32  
Row 2:  44  73   // This has shifted 2 columns. 

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 14.807 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

The First function lets the user name and define the dimensions of the matrix which is then populated from a .txt file containing 10x10 integers.

The second function displays the matrix and the third calculates the trace.

The fourth function asks the user to choose a 2x2 matrix, which is a subset of the original matrix. The 2x2 matrix contents must be stored in a new struct matrix, along with its name and size.

What I "think" I have done, is to ask the user where to start the sub-matrix and stored the values at k and l, I then use these values as an index.

Where I believe my problem occurs is in passing these vales to the new matrix, in the nested for loops I have incremented i and j to index the new matrix and l and k to index the matrix I am passing values from.

NOTE: I have never seen 2 values being incremented in a for loop before so I expect it is not doing what I "think" it is doing as row 2 of the sub matrix has shifted 2 columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Off topic: a lower case "L"  is not the happiest choice of variable name. They are too easy to confuse with the number 1. If you don't instinctively avoid that choice, you are setting yourself up for a difficult debugging session in the future.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the advice, I will keep in mind moving forward.

Comment: `struct matrix m1, struct matrix *m2` seems inconsistent. Why is one of the arguments a pointer and one not?

Comment: @JohnColeman I believe the problem is in the way I am passing values in my nested for loops, row 2 of the sub matrix is +2 columns to where I am trying to get it. I have included the functions and function body to try be as specific as possible, I am not very experienced with programming so my apologies if my question is ambiguous.

Comment: @JohnColeman the functions were predetermined so I had no choice but to use them as declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your l that is incremented in the innermost loop is the culprit

> for(j=0; j<2; j++,l++)

you need to reinitialize it

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++,k++)
        {
             printf("Row %d:\t", i+1);

             for(j=0; j<2; j++,l++)
                 {
                    (m2->mValues[i][j]) = ((m1).mValues[k-1][l-1]);
                    printf("%d\t",(m2->mValues[i][j])); 
                 }
                 printf("\n");
                 l=l-2;
        }
```

Because in the first row l is incremented twice, in the second row it's incremented twice again.

I'd advise you to avoid one letter variables and especially "l" as @JohnColeman said since they are a nightmare at debugging.

Comment: Wow! This has solved my nightmare and thought me something new, thank you very much :)

Comment: On another related point, is the way I have written the for loop a logical method or are there preferred methods for doing the same task?

Comment: the for loop is okay, it's just how you name your variables that's not readable, and also you can use m2-> as in the example instead of (*m2). it's equivalent but as you can see easier to read

Comment: I did notice you used -> instead and a quick search showed me it much more intuitive. Thank you for the help and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your index `l` should be reset to the initial value when you exit the second loop (`j` loop).

In your case, this is what your indexes look like during execution:

```
    loop i => i=0, k=3, j=0, l=3  
    loop j => i=0, k=3, j=0, l=3  
    loop j => i=0, k=3, j=1, l=4
    exit loop j => i=0, k=3, j=2, l=5  
    loop i => i=1, k=4, j=2, l=5 
    so on...
```

So your indexes are corrupted when you exit the second loop !

Comment: thank you, it looks obvious when you look at it like that, this problem has given me a headache for the last 2 days.